How to create topics in telegram chat with telethon
@loader.tds
class testr(loader.Module):
    '''name'''
    strings = {
        "name": "test",   
    }
    async def client_ready(self, client, db):
        self.test_channel, _ = await utils.asset_channel(
            self._client,
            "Test - chat",
            "check descr",
            silent=True,
            archive=True,
            _folder="m",
            
        )   
        await self.client(functions.channels.InviteToChannelRequest(self.test_channel, ['@my_bot']))
           
        await self.client(functions.channels.EditAdminRequest(
                channel=self.test_channel,
                user_id="@my_bot",
                admin_rights=ChatAdminRights(ban_users=True, post_messages=True, edit_messages=True),
                rank="xTest",
            )
        )

    def __init__(self):

I'm trying to create a group and topics in it using a user bot on a telethon. I can't find anywhere in the documentation how to properly work with topics. I only figured out how to write messages in a certain topic. But I can't figure out how to create it and find out the topic ID.
Here is a pre-launch code that successfully creates a group and invites the necessary users to it.

You can create a forum using CreateChannelRequest
Create a topic using CreateForumTopicRequest
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import CreateChannelRequest, CreateForumTopicRequest
import asyncio

client = TelegramClient(...)

async def main():
    # Creating a forum:
    forum = await client(CreateChannelRequest(
        title = 'FORUM_NAME',
        about = 'ABOUT',
        forum = True
    ))
    forum_id = forum.updates[1].channel_id

    # Creating a topic:
    topic = await client(CreateForumTopicRequest(
        channel = forum_id,
        title = 'TOPIC_NAME'
    ))
    topic_id = topic.updates[0].id

    # Send a message to the topic
    await client.send_message(
        entity = topic_id,
        message = 'MESSAGE_TEXT',
        reply_to = topic.updates[0].id
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.start()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

You can also convert an existing group into a forum using ToggleForumRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import ToggleForumRequest

await client(ToggleForumRequest(
    channel = YOUR_GROUP,
    enabled = True
)

